# Convert rgb color to x,y direction and back

Tags: java, android, colors, direction

Imagine round color pallet [like this](http://mudcu.be/sphere/#).

I am building a game(Android) in which you can draw line and when you drawing it you're creating vector between each two points. I need to transform this direction to color on the pallet. So when you draw, the color of the line will depend on your swipe direction.
I need to transform color to direction too. Can't figure out relation between 3 rgb params and x,y direction.
Of course I could limit number of colors to, for example 8. Then create array and every cell will represent direction of different color. But I wonder if it possible to use all of the colors without allocating tons of memory or using unnecessary if\else's?

Update:
Thanks to domi's advice I was able to do what I wanted. Thanx man!

That's how I converted vector to color:

```
double angle = Math.atan2(vector_x, vector_y) * 57.2957795;
double final_angle = angle<0? 360 + angle:angle;
int myRGBColor = Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{(float) final_angle, saturation, brightness} );
```

And that's how I converted color to vector:

```
int sample = bmp.getPixel( (int)X, (int)Y);
//int a = (sample >> 24) & 255;
int r = (sample >> 16) & 255;
int g = (sample >> 8) & 255;
int b = sample & 255;

float[] hsv = new float[3];
android.graphics.Color.RGBToHSV(r, g, b, hsv);
float hue = hsv[0]; 
vector_x =  Math.toDegrees( Math.sin(  Math.toRadians(hue) ) );
vector_y =  Math.toDegrees( Math.cos(  Math.toRadians(hue) ) );
```

Everyone is welcome to [play my game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enti.roll2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a vector you can use the degree to calculate the color with the HSL system.
If you go on the [round color pallet](http://mudcu.be/sphere/#) you can see that Saturation (S) is always 100 and Luminance (L) is always 50 then you just have to use the degree (0-360) to have the HUE and have a complete HSL color (degree, 100, 50).
Then you can transforme RGB to HSL and HSL to RGB

Comment: You can accept his answer - just click the tick button.